# Testing in Android Studio with Selendroid

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

I want to test Apps with and in Android Studios!
I know already Espresso, Robolectric, Robotium etc.
But the most tutorials are with Eclipse like testing with Selendroid!
Now I want to test with Selendroid writing the tests in Android Studio.

Do you have any suggestions how to get through or any tutorial links?
I would also be happy for other suggestions for Testing Android, mostly
UI testing with many fragments?

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK provides the following tools to support automated, functional UI testing on your application:

- uiautomatorviewer - A GUI tool to scan and analyze the UI components
  of an Android application.
- uiautomator - A Java library containing APIs to create customized
  functional UI tests, and an execution engine to automate and run the
  tests.

To use these tools, you must have the following versions of the Android development tools installed: * Android SDK Tools, Revision 21 or higher * Android SDK Platform, API 16 or higher

Read about Analyzing Your Application's UI, Preparing to Test, Creating uiautomator Tests, Building and Deploying Your uiautomator Tests, Running uiautomator Tests you can here http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#running

Comment: I know them allready, but thanks. But I have and want to use Selendroid for automation. So any suggestions?

Comment: @AliceC These links I hope  will be helpful for you. Introduction to Selendroid, getting started with Selendroid, setting up Selendroid environment, how to launch Selendroid, Selendroid basic command and also starting your first test with Selendroid: 
http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selendroid.html

After this basic knowledges you may go to this tutorial:
http://selenium-breakthrough.blogspot.com/2014/04/step-by-step-tutorial-for-running-your.html
http://www.videonel.com/video/x1he3aw_selendroid-android-mobile-application-test-automation-step-by-step-demonstration-detailed_tech#.VQp48eGr